# Select users who's first appearance has a referrer value of adwords and appear more then once

Tags: mysql

I have a table of users, one for each order. Every order comes with a referrer. I want to select those users who's first appearance in the table (by order_id) has a referrer of 'adwords' and have more then one entry in the table.

The columns here to use are:
order_id - every new order gets a new order_id that is one more then the last one
billing_email - the users email, which is  how we know what user they are
referrer - this is set to adwords when they come in via adwords.

So far i have this:

```
select count(*) as num_entries, billing_email from tblOrder where referrer='adwords' GROUP BY billing_email HAVING count(*) > 1
```

That's not doing what i'm looking for.

What i'm like to see a results is something like this:

```
2, user@domain.com
4, user2@domain.com
```

etc. thus telling me how many repeat orders people coming in from adwords make.

Comment: The query above does so most of what i'm looking for. it will return the count just like i'm asking for, but it wont make sure these users FIRST entry in the table had a referrer of adwords. That the part i'm unsure of how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query needs to be a little bit more complicated to work exactly as you want.

First you need an inner query that will allow you to get the minimum order_id for each billing_email. It also lets you count the total entries for each billing_email so you can only include users with more than one.

Then you have to use that minimum order_id to join back into the same table and get the rest of the data from that row. This will allow you to see if each user's minimum order_id was referred from adwords.

```
SELECT T1.TableEntries, T1.billing_email FROM
(
    SELECT billing_email, MIN(order_id) AS UsersFirstOrderID
    , COUNT(*) AS TableEntries
    FROM tblOrder 
    GROUP BY billing_email
    HAVING TableEntries>1
) AS T1
JOIN
tblOrder AS T2
ON T1.UsersFirstOrderID=T2.order_id
AND T2.referrer='adwords'
```